# Time stamp is not capturing on cell value update and this value is formula based

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Time stamp on cell value update and this value is formula based. Let me be specific when a value is updated manually in the sheet, time stamp is triggering. However, when the cell value is updating, which is derived from **formula** (based on another field ) then time stamp is not triggering.

In the below code value "a" and "b" is derived from another sheet for example so when I am entering the value as "a" in another sheet or any  formula based event occurs then time stamp is not triggering. I need help .

```
function onEdit()
 {
  var tradeden =2;  // Column Number of "B"
  var saquib = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var bhai = saquib.getActiveSheet();
  var changedRange = bhai.getActiveRange();
  var timestamp =  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "IST", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");


  if (changedRange.getColumn() ==tradeden ) 
         {
    // An edit has occurred in Column B
    var state = changedRange.getValue();
    if (state=="a")
    {
    var adjacent = bhai.getRange(changedRange.getRow(),tradeden+2);
    adjacent.setValue(timestamp);
    }
     if (state=="b")
     {
    var adjacent1 = bhai.getRange(changedRange.getRow(),tradeden+3);
    adjacent1.setValue(timestamp);
     }

   }
   }
```

Comment: Your code is in JS, not in Python. Do not do tag spamming.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is normal behavior.  Simple triggers are meant to be activated by user actions.

I suppose that you could add the cells on other sheets to the onEdit function but you'd probably have to call the sheet that you refer to as active by it's name since it would not be the active sheet at that point.